# SSRS Compare Two Datasets For Missing Ids

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

In SSRS report I have two data sources from two different servers. I have a dataset for each data source and would like to return in a tablix the ids that are in dataset 1 but not in dataset 2.
So if dataset 1 has ids 1,2,3,4,5 and dataset 2 has ids 1,2,3 the report should display 4 and 5. I cannot link the servers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

---

### Common Lookup method

*This is the way most people would probably do this*

---

Use the `Lookup()` function.

Set the tablix row's `hidden` property to something like

```
=ISNOTHING(
 Lookup(Fields!IDa.Value,Fields!IDb.Value,Fields!IDb.Value,"Dataset2")
) = False
```

The above, for clarity, assumes the ID column in dataset1 is called `IDa` and the ID column from dataset2 is called `IDb`. It will stil work if they have the same name (e.g. 'ID')

**Note:** Dataset name must be in quotes and is case sensitive.

Using this method returns all the rows and simply hides the ones that do not match your criteria. This may not be ideal if you're exporting the data. If not, see the alternative version below.

---

### Alternative method

*For reasonably small datasets - parameter method
... and because I thought it was an interesting approach...*

---

This second method uses a hidden parameter and is easy to setup assuming you have a reasonable small number of records.

Using your example, create a parameter called `List2` and set its default and available values BOTH to your `Dataset2` query (from your example above). Make the parameter multi-value. You can make this parameter hidden once it's working.

Now Your `Dataset1` query can be a simple query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id NOT IN (@List2)
```

@List2 will contain the values from datset2 (1,2 and 3) so the query will return only the remaining values.

**Note** I named the datasets to match your example but the datasets must be created in the order above.

Comment: I want to display the no matches, not hide them. if dataset1 has 1,2,3,4,5 and dataset2 has 1,2,3 i want to display 4,5 and hide 1,2,3

Comment: If you used the lookup method, just remove the `= False` part. If you used the parameter method, change the `NOT IN` to `IN`

Comment: unless I am missing something this does not appear to be working, it keeps displaying 1,2 and 3. This is what I have in the text boxes visibility =IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!id.Value,Fields!id2.Value,Fields!id2.Value,"DataSet2"))

Comment: also when i try the parameter method i am able to create parameter using dataset2, both default and available, that part works fine. When I enter this into dataset1 query, select * from dbo.tbl_data_source_1 where id not in (@List2) i get the following error: must declare the scalar variable "@List2"

Comment: i think i got it working using the parameter method, need to do more testing. Thanks.

Comment: just be careful that your dataset variable `@List2` matches the report parameter name (minus the @). It is case sensitive.